# Decode audio and play intro then looped part

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a song, consisting of intro (I), a part to be looped (L), and ending (E). I don't want the ending to be played at all, i.e. audio file song = I + L + E, audio played = I + L + L + ...

I succeeded to do that by separating the intro and the loop into two files, but I want to do that "on-the-fly" on the client side.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Audio API provides  `AudioBufferSourceNode.loopStart` and `AudioBufferSourceNode.loopEnd` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode)) precisely for that. You have to remember to set `AudioBufferSourceNode.loop = true` also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play the file using Web Audio (e.g. decode into an AudioBuffer using decodeAudioData() and then play the sound with BufferSourceNodes), then it's easy to do by pointing two BufferSource Nodes at the buffer with different offsets, and looping the second one.

Web Audio uses doubles (not floats) - so the statement "this is much more accurate than float seconds" isn't generally true (doubles have around 15 decimal places of accuracy).  (Depends on the absolute value, of course.)  It's more than accurate enough to play with sample-accuracy (i.e. to not glitch between the values); if you're concerned, though, just cross-fade between them.

If your goal is really just to produce an audio file with that part looped, that's a little different; but it sounds like you want playback.